# setLocationRelative to another JFrame

Tags: java, swing

How do I go about setting a JFrame class relative to another JFrame class?

I know that if I create a JFrame in the same class as the one I want to center I call `setLocationRelativeTo(this)`, but due to the class getting long I cut it down into smaller JFrame classes.

So far i'm having to use `setLocationRelativeTo(null)` to center it but this is not very good when I want the JFrame that is popping up to be ontop of the main JFrame.

Comment: JFrame class? I think you mean JFrame _instance_.

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant JFrame instance.

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple frames in your application. For a secondary window you should use a JDialog. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636/the-use-of-multiple-jframes-good-bad-practice. Then you just use `dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);`

Comment: Thank you, I'll implement a dialogue instead.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getLocationOnScreen() set it relative to this. But I agree on multiple popups, too annoying for the user.